# How does an Android time based app work?

Tags: android

How does an Android alarm app or any other time based notifications app like Calendar, Clock, etc work? More specifically, how does it show up the notifications at exactly the time specified by the user? Does it constantly run in the background and as soon as the required time comes up, does it show the notification? Or does it schedule the notification in Android's kernel before exiting? I am working on an app that needs to give the user notifications at times specifies by him. I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Check this:
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you mean is to create an alarm, you can see [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/samples/android/+/d26c23e38fd2368d078984fc864591daaee189c5/background/alarms/Scheduler/src/com/example/android/scheduler?autodive=0%2F%2F).